# Merging two text files based on the columns in Python without using Pandas/CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I've two subject's marks lists as raw input data as mentioned below

```
English.txt
 
First_Name Last_Name English_Marks
ABC         PQR        67
DEF         LMN        80

Maths.txt

First_Name Last_Name Maths_Marks
ABC         PQR        90
DEF         LMN        75
```

I want to generate an output.txt file that will contain a merged list of above two text files as given  below:

```
Output.txt
First_Name Last_Name English_Marks Maths_Marks Total_Marks
ABC         PQR        67             90          157
DEF         LMN        80             75          155
```

Can anyone please give me solution to this in Python without using Pandas/NumPy/CSV

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What should happen if a name appears in only one of the files?  Are the names going to be in the same order in both files?

Comment: Do you know how to write basic Python file operations?  Open a file, and read it line by line?  How to split a string into a list of strings, etc?  As long as you know how to use Python strings, lists, and files it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: If you want to do this without pandas why did you include that tag?  And why the `numpy` tag?

Comment: @chris I tried with writing list of strings but faced issues like marks can be common....Names are not gonna common.. and sorting of lists without changing the order

Answer (score 2):

You seem new to Python
I am Writing a long Version of the code to keep it understandable.
here I am Considering the names in both the files are sorted and are same.
If the case is otherwise(names in both the files are somewhat different): You need to Create Dictionary, Please reply if that is needed..

Below is a solution with CSV, If you do not want CSV then just split the text to create a list of lists.

```
lines= txt.split("\n")
New_list =[]
For line in lines:
    elements = line.split(" ")
    new_list.append(elements)
```

Rest of the code below will be the same. (Just remove the csv)
If the names are not in the same order in both the files, Then Try creating Dict with Keys as 'First_name'+'Last_name'

*--------------------*-------------------------------------

```
import csv


eng_file=open('english.csv','r')
maths_file=open('maths.csv','r')

eng_reader= list(csv.reader(eng_file))
maths_reader=list(csv.reader(maths_file))


output_list=[]

for i in range(len(eng_reader)):
    output_line=[]
    
    # Creating Headers
    if i==0:
        output_line=['First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'English_Marks', 'Maths_Marks', 'Total_Marks']
    
    # Creating data 
    else:
    
        english_line=eng_reader[i]
        maths_line = maths_reader[i]

        if english_line[0]==maths_line[0] and english_line[1]==maths_line[1]:
            output_line=[english_line[0],english_line[1],english_line[2],maths_line[2],int(english_line[2])+int(maths_line[2])]
    output_list.append(output_line)


with open('output.csv','w+') as out:
    writer=csv.writer(out)
    for output_line in output_list:
        writer.writerow(output_line)
```